# How to build full Android AOSP images for Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: android, android-source, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to make a build of an OS using AOSP. I have downloaded the project, made a build for ARM64 but not able to get the vendor image for Raspberry Pi 4. I got ramdisk.img, system.img but not the vendor image.

Although it says build completed successfully, I am still not able to see vendor image

I did some research and made build with "make -j16" command.
Then I tried to make the build again with "make ramdisk systemimage vendorimage" command.

Got the ramdisk and systemimage but still no luck.

Comment: Tushar, what manifest and sources you are using?

Comment: Downloaded the project from google repo only.
https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download/downloading

Answer (score 0):

To build AOSP 14 for Raspberry Pi 4 you can use this instruction

https://github.com/raspberry-vanilla/android_local_manifest?tab=readme-ov-file

How to build:

1. Establish [Android build environment](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/start/initializing) and install [repo](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download#installing-repo).
2. Install additional packages:

   sudo apt-get install bc coreutils dosfstools e2fsprogs fdisk kpartx mtools ninja-build pkg-config python3-pip

   sudo pip3 install meson mako jinja2 ply pyyaml dataclasses
3. Initialize repo:

   repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-14.0.0_r20

   curl -o .repo/local_manifests/manifest_brcm_rpi.xml -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberry-vanilla/android_local_manifest/android-14.0/manifest_brcm_rpi.xml --create-dirs

Or optionally, you can reduce download size by creating a shallow clone and removing unneeded projects:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-14.0.0_r20 --depth=1
curl -o .repo/local_manifests/manifest_brcm_rpi.xml -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberry-vanilla/android_local_manifest/android-14.0/manifest_brcm_rpi.xml --create-dirs
curl -o .repo/local_manifests/remove_projects.xml -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberry-vanilla/android_local_manifest/android-14.0/remove_projects.xml
```

4. Sync source code:

   repo sync
5. Setup Android build environment:

   . build/envsetup.sh
6. Select the device rpi4 and build target (tablet UI, tv for Android TV, or car for Android Automotive):

   lunch aosp_rpi4-userdebug
   lunch aosp_rpi4_tv-userdebug
   lunch aosp_rpi4_car-userdebug
7. Compile:

   make bootimage systemimage vendorimage -j$(nproc)
8. Make flashable image for the device rpi4:

   ./rpi4-mkimg.sh

or this for automotive AAOS 14

https://medium.com/make-android/android-automotive-os-14-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-e83b2f8ca353